# Handling kafka clients updates in kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I have a Kafka cluster running on AWS MSK with Kafka producer and consumer go clients running in kubernetes. The producer is responsible for sending the stream of data to Kafka. I need help solving the following problems:

1. Let's say, there is some code change in producer code and have to redeploy it in kubernetes. How can I do that? Since the data is continuously generated, I cannot just simply stop the already running producer and deploy the updated one. In this case, I will lose the data between the update process.
2. Sometimes due to a panic(golang) in the code, the client crashes, but since it is running as a pod, kubernetes restarts it. I am not able to understand as to whether it's a good thing or bad.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I would suggest having rolling update of your deployment in the cluster.
For second, that is the general behavior of deployments in kubernetes. I could think of an external monitoring solution that de-deploys your application or stops handling requests in case of a `panic`.
It would be better if you could explain why exactly you need such kind of behavior.!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the second question, I don't exactly need such behavior but I was getting that from k8s. You mention an external solution, what would that be?

Comment: Maybe a log analyser or log based trigger through some tool. You could export your application's log through side car containers in each pod and then use those logs to configure triggers.